# Opencv Android- Problems using native c++ code in android studio 2.2.2

Tags: android, opencv, computer-vision

I want to use native C++ code of Opencv in android studio 2.2.2 .I tried about a week reading tutorials but that didn't work for me.I am new to opencv and android.It would be quite helpful if I get step by step instruction for doing this.

Comment: [THIS PAGE](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html) has enough of info. What more do you want? Did you go through this?

Comment: It shows steps for older version of android studio which is hard to follow.Android studio 2.2.2 uses cmake for building native code.@Jeru Luke